# "Schottischer Schenker"?

Tags: single-word-request

Der englische Ausdruck "an Indian giver" (jemand, der etwas schenkt und später sein Geschenk zurückverlangt oder zurücknimmt) wurde als "Schottischer Schenker" ins Deutsche übersetzt. Ich habe im Netz nach Erklärung (oder auch nach sonstigen Informationen gesucht), aber leider nichts gefunden. Ist es eine vom Übersetzer frei erfundene Phrase, bei der er einfach Gebrauch von Alliteration macht, oder gibt es im Deutschen tatsächlich so einen Ausdruck?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: "Schottischer Schenker" habe ich auch noch nie gehört. Bin mir auch keiner direkten deutschen Übersetzung bewußt. Was aber nicht heißen muß, daß es diese nicht gibt ... Aber irgendwie hört sich das rassistisch an ... amerikanisches englisch ?

Comment: "US and Canadian offensive": https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/indian-giver

Comment: Aus welchem Buch / Text stammt die Übersetzung? Evtl mit Zitat. Google / Bing finden dafür keine Textstellen und wie @a_donda habe ich den so auch noch nie gehört.

Comment: Es ist aus TBBT: Wolowitz spricht mit seinem Spezi und mit diesem pun spielt noch darauf an, dass Raj Inder ist und sagt: "So you're an Indian giver..." Ich war neugierig darauf, wie man das ins Deutsche übertragen würde, schaltete die Untertitel ein und sah „schottischer Schenker“ =) Da meine Suchanfrage keine passenden Treffer geliefert hat, dachte ich mir, vllt nahm derjenige, der die Untertitel verfasst hat, die Schotten, weil sie den gleichen Anfangslaut mit „Schenker“ haben. Dass die Schotten als geizig gelten, wusste ich nicht ; )

Comment: a_donda: yessss AmE

Comment: Die relevante Redewendung ist "Geschenkt ist geschenkt - wiederholen ist gestohlen!". Womöglich könnte man daraus etwas ableiten. Üblich ist aber kein solches Wort.

Comment: In Bezug auf mit Nationalitäten stereotypisch verbundene Einschränkungen bei Geschenken fällt mir im Deutschen nur das Danaergeschenk ein, das aus der Aeneis kommt, nämlich als "Φοβοῦ τοὺς Δαναοὺς καὶ δῶρα φέροντας" bzw. "*Timeo Danaos et dona ferentes*". Hier handelt es sich um Geschenke, die eine Heimtücke enthalten. -  Das wäre dann wohl ein "griechisches Geschenk", aber damit jemand diese Anspielung versteht, muss er schon sehr klassischgebildet sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schotten gelten klischeehaft als sehr geizig. Ein schottischer Schenker ist also ein geiziger Schenker. Mit der gelieferten ursprünglichen Bedeutung, schenkt er also etwas, ist dann aber so geizig, dass er es zurücknimmt.

Comment: Gibt's den Begriff wirklich im Deutschen ?

Comment: Den Begriff habe ich noch nie gehört. Aber damit kann ich definitiv mehr Anfangen (und auf die Bedeutung schließen) als bei einem indischen Schenker/Geber.

Comment: Infinitezero: vielen Dank für die Erklärung! =)

Comment: Moin,

einen 'Schottischen Schenker' kannte ich nicht. Mir fällt aber auch kein passender Begriff ein. Ich hätte es vermutlich als Geschenk mit Rückhohlleine sinngemäß übersetzt.

Solche Phrasen sind länderspezifisch gerne auf andere Länder gemünzt.

Kondome heißen hier Pariser, Franzosen nennen sie wohl Engländer.

Ein Weggehen ohne Abschied kenne ich als "polnischer Abgang", in Frankreich ist das wohl der deutsche Abgang.

Comment: Bru, vielen Dank! Sehr interessant! Bei uns ist es hingegen der französische Abgang =)

Comment: Nein, diesen Ausdruck (schottischer Schenker) gibt es im Deutschen (bisher) nicht. Ein normaler Angehöriger der Sprechgemeinschaft des Deutschen würde unter "schottischer Schenker", wenn schon, dann einen geizigen Schenker im Sinne von "Er gibt nur wenig Geld für das Geschenk aus" vermuten.

Comment: Der Schluss vom Geiz auf das Zurücknehmen des Geschenks überdehnt, was man unter sprichwörtlichem Geiz versteht. Wenn man erst das Verhalten schildert, und dann denjenigen einen schottischen Schenker nennt, wird der Leser verstehen, dass damit Geiz als Motiv ausgedrückt werden soll. Aber wenn jemand nur beschreibt, X sei ein schottischer Schenker wird niemand auf die Idee kommen, dass derjenige sein Geschenk zurückverlangt hat, genauso wenig, wie wenn jemand "geiziger Schenker" schreibt. Es gibt dafür keine Redewendung.